# Prove that $f(z)=f(re^{i \theta})= \sqrt{r}e^{i \frac{\theta}{2}}$ is discontinuous

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

I would like to prove thatthe multiform function $f(z)=f(re^{i \theta})= \sqrt{r}e^{i \frac{\theta}{2}}$ is not continuous for $z \in (- \infty, 0)$ and $\theta \in (-\pi, \pi]$. I think I could use the reciprocal of a continuous fonction. The problem is I don't know the validity of my comprenhension of the reciprocity : there exists $\epsilon > 0$, for each $\delta > 0$, $|z-z_0| < \delta \implies |f(z)-f(z_0)| \geq \epsilon  $.

Am I right? Is there exist another way I can use the show the discontinuity of $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're using the word "reciprocal" as I would use the word "negation".  A function $f$ is continuous if

$$\forall x_0 \forall \epsilon > 0\exists \delta \,:\, \forall x, |x-x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x_0) - f(x)| < \epsilon. $$

It's a complex statement, so its negation is also going to be complex.  The negation of this statement is

$$\exists x_0 \exists \epsilon > 0 \, : \, \forall \delta > 0 \exists x \, : |x - x_0| < \delta \land \, |f(x_0) - f(x)| \ge \epsilon.$$

(A long-winded post about negating complex statements is [here](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/basic-logic-relationships-between-statements-negation/).)  In plainer language:  There is a point, $x_0$, where continuity breaks down, meaning that you can find $x$ as close to $x_0$ as you like so that $f(x_0)$ is not close to $f(x)$.  This is what mrf did above; he found a point (here, $-1$) so that points arbitrarily close to $-1$ are mapped close to $-i$ rather than $i$.  In terms of the logical statement above, this corresponds to a choice of $x_0 = -1$, $\epsilon = 1$, and choosing $x = e^{-i(\pi + \delta)}$  Then, $|x - x_0| < \delta$, but $|f(x) - f(x_0)| > \epsilon$, **no matter how tiny $\delta$ is.**

In many cases, the negation of sequential continuity (as mrf used) is simpler; you just have to find one sequence $(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ such that $x_i \to x_0$ but $f(x_i) \not \to f(x)$.  (Here, $x_0$ has the same meaning as before; it's the point where continuity "breaks down".)

Answer (score 3):

The function is continuous as a function of two real variables $r$ and $\theta$, but not as a function of $z$.

Note that $f(-1) = f(1\cdot e^{i\pi}) = 1\cdot e^{i\pi/2} = i$. On the other hand, if $z_\varepsilon = 1\cdot e^{i(-\pi+\varepsilon)}$, where $\varepsilon > 0$ is small, then $z_\varepsilon \to -1$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$, **but**
$$
f(z_\varepsilon) = e^{i(-\pi+\varepsilon)/2} \to -i \neq f(-1)
$$
as $\varepsilon \to 0$. This shows that $f$ is not sequentially continuous (in particular not continuous).

Comment: Your answer is right! Should you able to prove it with the reciprocal of continuous function?